# Apply "thickness" to a minimal surface

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

By definition a minimal surface has no volume. But my goal is to give the minimal surface some volume. Is there a mathematical way to do this? I found [a thread in a forum of a math visualization tool](http://k3dsurf.s4.bizhat.com/k3dsurf-ftopic2-0-asc-0.html) where people suggested a solution, but it does not work for me at all.

The concrete problem I am looking at is the gyroid:

$$
F(x,y,z) = \sin(x) \times \cos(y) + \sin(y) \times \cos(z) + \sin(z) \times \cos(x) = t
$$

Another related question: I get that the gyroid is only defined in $t \in  [-1.5, 1.5]$ and that the value of t determines the volume fractions of the two divided spaces. Is there a way to determine how much percent of the volume is belonging to which area given a value for $t$?